# insert sql to database not inserting properly

Tags: php, mysql, cart, sql-insert

I want to insert my data to database, however, it doesn't work out properly such as, when I have 4 products added to cart, it will only insert two out of four. And the subtotal appears such that it captures the first amount of the product as my subtotal and then it shows the total amount for the whole products. And my quantity doesn't insert in my database.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price per item</th>
        <th>Total cost</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM productsc WHERE id_product IN (";
    foreach ($_SESSION['cartCity'] as $id => $value) {
        $sql .= $id . ",";
    }
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1) . ") ORDER BY name ASC";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $total_price = 0;
    if (!empty($query)) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $subtotal = $_SESSION['cartCity'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] * $row['price'];
            $total_price += $subtotal;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quantity-<?php echo $row['id_product']; ?>" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cartCity'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']; ?>" /></td>
                <td><?php echo "$" . $row['price']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo"$" . $_SESSION['cartCity'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] * $row['price']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO order_details (name,quantity,price,subtotal) VALUES ('" . $row['name'] . "','" . $quantity . "','" . $row['price'] . "','" . $total_price . "')";
                $query2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total price:</td>
        <td><?php echo"$" . $total_price; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Use a database library that allows to be configured throwing exceptions *and* that allows to work better with variables. Why not choose PDO´?

Comment: there is not much an error but the quantity does not show up in the database. and the subtotal is not adding up properly  @MikeBrant

Answer (score 0):

possibly because you call $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) inside a loop doing the same, meaning that the outer loop is only going to run half of the time and you will only enter every other item

try

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $subtotal = $_SESSION['cartCity'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] * $row['price'];
        $total_price += $subtotal;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity-<?php echo $row['id_product']; ?>" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cartCity'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo "$" . $row['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo"$" . $_SESSION['cartCity'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] * $row['price']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO order_details (name,quantity,price,subtotal) VALUES ('" . $row['name'] . "','" . $quantity . "','" . $row['price'] . "','" . $total_price . "')";
        $query2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

    }
```

Comment: so if i run them outside the loop, it will be better?

Comment: I think that you do not need the if statement: if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

Comment: alright, so what do i replace it with instead? just $query will do? @otternq

Comment: I would just remove the line above $sql2 = "Insert..." and the line just below $query2 = mysql_query(...). you shouldn't have to add anything if I understand your problem

Comment: if that is the case, then it won't go into my databse. I need the datas. It works well if i don't need the insert sql @otternq

Comment: the quantity still does not go into my database ): @otternq